# How to handle no matches (undefined) returned by find()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering components in React based off of properties of an object. The problem is that initially there are no properties for the render, which is the way it should be, but the .find() breaks the code:

```
pallets.find((pallet) => pallet.selected).config.map(.......)
```

The problem is that initially no pallets are selected, so there is no config.

Is there a way to solve this problem inline, without extracting pallets.find() result into a variable and then doing an if check and only then proceeding with the map? It would make the React code much easier if I can keep it inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep it inline:

```
pallets.find((pallet) => pallet.selected) && pallets.find((pallet) => pallet.selected).config.map(.......)
```

If you are using Typescript or your version of JavaScript supports [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) you can do:

```
pallets.find((pallet) => pallet.selected)?.config?.map(.......)
```

Answer (score 0):

please use

```js
pallets.length > 0 && pallets.find((pallet) => pallet.selected).config.map(.......)
```

Comment: Not going to work, pallets is an array of objects that always exists, I need to pick the pallet that has the .selected property set to true, but initially all are false, so thats why I dont get config. The answer by klugjo is what I was looking for.

Comment: Can you try this then....   pallets.find((pallet) => pallet.selected) && pallets.find((pallet) => pallet.selected).config.map(.......)

Comment: Will work, but it will run through the array twice. The optional chaining operator mentioned by klugjo above is what solves this cleanly.

Comment: @Darkbound  Yeah for Typescript its perfect

Comment: @Darkbound I fear it won't work in Internet Explorer

Comment: Its local project, Internet Explorer doesn't matter :) but good to know!

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to limit the calls of .find() running it only once, you can wrap them with conditionals:

```
((pallets.find((pallet) => pallet.selected) || {}).config || []).map(.......)
```

Comment: I dont want to limit the calls of find, I just want it to stop at find, if it doesnt find anything.

Comment: Right, but if you use: pallets.find((pallet) => pallet.selected) && pallets.find((pallet) => pallet.selected) you will be running through your pallet array twice, which isn't efficient.

Comment: and I am not doing that, nor did I ever say that I am considering it :)

Comment: I have commented bellow it that I have used the "optional chaining" answer, not the double find :)

Comment: But it still does the same thing under the hood, so it still equally inefficient, that's all my point is.

Comment: Hmm, well I don't know about that, you may be right, still in this particular instance I will never be dealing with some enormous array of objects, so performance will not be impacted even if that is true. I was mainly looking for a clean syntax.

Comment: Awesome!  If it's not an issue then and conciseness is what's your after then optional chaining would be the way to go.